# How to partial update DataGrid - only for one column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to do partial update of a `DataGrid` in `WPF`?
I want to update only one column and all values inside it of a `DataGrid` without refreshing the whole grid. I am using timer which will reload the grid with latest data every XX seconds.
How can I do that?

There is double click event on the grid row, so when the whole grid refreshes if the user clicks at this moment it won't handle the `double click`. Same is if I have `HyperLink` column. I believe if I partial update can handle such case?

Binding now is:

```
dataGrid.DataContext = myCollection;
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

*And an idea for those who do refreshing of grids and have similar issue:
I refresh the `DataGrid` on timer tick event only when the value of `myCollection` has changed.*

Comment: Use Binding to bind your dataGrid to ItemsSource instead of loading it manually from code behind.

Comment: Do you use manual binding update mode?

Comment: If you're not using a `Binding` , you should edit the question to show what kind of object is your `myCollection`

Comment: I have developed my own collection type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF we work with data elements rather than UI elements... instead of trying to manipulate the column value of each row in the `DataGrid`, you should think about data binding a collection of custom class instances to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property and then just update whichever property of the classes that is data bound to your column. See this example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

...

```
foreach (YourClass item in Items)
{
    item.PropertyThatIsDataBoundToYourColumn = someNewValue;
}
```

To make this work properly, your custom `YourClass` class should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).